# How to install recovery and rom on blank Samsung i9000

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s, unbricking

I wanted to install CM on my Samsung Galaxy S, and while trying to enable ClockworkMod recovery, I somehow managed to partition it. Now the only thing that appears is the screen with the model number, and I can enter download mode (but not in recovery mode). I tried to install recovery with Odin (I found a tar file) but that failed. Is there any chance that I can get my phone working again?

Comment: You mean to say you CAN'T enter download mode, right?

Comment: No, that is the only thing I can do with my phone (edited the question)

Comment: if u can enter the download mode then your phone can be saved. Sites like XDA forum have a lot of tutorials on flashing a rom. here is one example: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1922461

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone dealing with the same issue, I've found a solution on this [link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1647890). It is for Froyo, but you can look on XDA-Developers for Gingerbread too, it is the same procedure.